# Best way of fixing relative path issue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I have a folder structure like this

```
root_folder
    package1
        __init__.py
        file1.py
    package2
        __init__.py
        file2.py
```

file1.py

```
def test1():
    print("in test1")
```

file2.py

```
from package1 import file1
def test2():
        print("in test2")
```

when I run `file2` from `root_folder` I am getting this error:

```
python3 package2/file2.py

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'
```

when I exported `python` path, it worked fine.

```
PYTHONPATH="/Users/me/root_folder:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH
```

I am from `java` background. I want to know is it the right approach? What is the best way of fixing relative path issues in `python`?

Answer (score 0):

Try just importing package1 rather than importing file1 from package1.

I’m not a genius at Python, I’m only intermediate level. But that’s what I’d try next.

Comment: when importing package1 getting this error now - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'

Answer (score 0):

Use '.' before package1. It means 'up directory'.

```
from .package1 import file1
def test2():
        print("in test2")
```

Comment: getting this error now - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.package1'; '__main__' is not a package